# Does OIDC make sense for B2B?

Tags: authentication, openid-connect

I'm implementing an API Gateway and have a very simple question about OIDC connect as an authentication method.

Does Open Id connect only suit the use case of B2C. i.e. I am a customer logging into a website, when i present my credentials to the resource server, it validates with the auth server and i get an access token.

Does it make sense to apply open id connect to B2B? i.e. I am an application trying to access an API. When I present my credentials to the resource server, it validates it with the auth server.

If it does if someone could point me out to some doco on differences between a user and an app for oidc that would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `B2B` means, but it looks like `M2M` (`machine-to-machine`), where you can use [client credentials OIDC flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials). OIDC offers also grant code/implicit flow for user authentication. Overview of available OIDC flows: https://auth0.com/docs/flows

Comment: Client Credentials Flow, is OAuth, not OIDC flow. OAuth (authorization) returns access token, OIDC (authentication) returns ID token (and usually also access token).

Comment: B2B is business-to-business, which is a specific scenario for M2M.